# Left join dont get all records

Tags: sql, left-join

I am trying to get all records from my tables (groups, fiches, clients, goals, factures) by using left join to get results, and get 0 if the user id is not present (ex : no goal assigned to the membre)
I dont know if i explain effectively but here is my query :

```
select CONCAT(s.firstname, ' ', s.lastname) AS Membre, g.achievement AS Objectif, count(l.assigned) AS `num_l`, count(c.id_fiche) AS `num_c`,
(count(c.id_fiche)/count(l.assigned))*100 AS `perc`, SUM(f.total) AS `glob`, (g.achievement - SUM(f.total)) AS `rest`, (SUM(f.total)/g.achievement)*100 AS `taux` 
from `groups` s 
LEFT JOIN `fiches` l ON s.id_membre=l.assigned LEFT JOIN `clients` c ON l.id=c.id_fiche 
LEFT JOIN `goals` g ON s.id_membre=g.id_membre LEFT JOIN `factures` f ON s.id_membre=f.addedfrom 
WHERE l.dateassigned BETWEEN  '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-31' AND f.status=2 
GROUP BY s.id_membre
```

All I get in the result is members who for whom the goal is assigned , but what i need is all members, and for whom the goal is not assigned get 0 in fields related to goal.
Thank you.

Comment: Here is my tables :
`groups(id_membre, firstname, email, password)`

`fiches(id, name, company, assigned, dateassigned)`

`clients(userid, phone, datecreated, id_fiche)`

`goals(id, goal_type, achievement, start_date, end_date, id_membre)`

`factures(id, clientid, total, status, addedfrom)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LEFT JOIN` is fine.  You have opted to turn it into an `INNER JOIN` by adding a `WHERE` clause.

When using `LEFT JOIN`, filtering conditions *on all but the first table* should be in the `ON` conditions.

```
select CONCAT(s.firstname, ' ', s.lastname) AS Membre, g.achievement AS Objectif, 
       count(l.assigned) AS `num_l`, count(c.id_fiche) AS `num_c`, 
       (count(c.id_fiche)/count(l.assigned))*100 AS `perc`, SUM(f.total) AS `glob`, (g.achievement - SUM(f.total)) AS `rest`,
      (SUM(f.total)/g.achievement)*100 AS `taux`
from `groups` s LEFT JOIN
     `fiches` l
     ON s.id_membre = l.assigned AND
        l.dateassigned BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-31' LEFT JOIN
     `clients` c
     ON l.id = c.id_fiche LEFT JOIN
     `goals` g
     ON s.id_membre = g.id_membre LEFT JOIN
     `factures` f
     ON s.id_membre = f.addedfrom AND f.status=2
GROUP BY s.id_membre
```

Comment: thank you but when i try it i didnt get the correct number of the staff, i have 8 members i get 5 records, and in the field of Membre i get `NULL`

Comment: @salaheddineKoraich . . . This query will keep *all* distinct value of `groups.id_membre`.

Comment: I dont know how but when i retried it works lol, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to chaneg you r query to -

```
select CONCAT(s.firstname, ' ', s.lastname) AS Membre,
       g.achievement AS Objectif,
       count(l.assigned) AS `num_l`,
       count(c.id_fiche) AS `num_c`,
       (count(c.id_fiche)/count(l.assigned))*100 AS `perc`,
       SUM(f.total) AS `glob`,
       (g.achievement - SUM(f.total)) AS `rest`,
       (SUM(f.total)/g.achievement)*100 AS `taux`
  from `groups` s
  LEFT JOIN `fiches` l ON s.id_membre=l.assigned
                       AND l.dateassigned BETWEEN  '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-31'
  LEFT JOIN `clients` c ON l.id=c.id_fiche
  LEFT JOIN `goals` g ON s.id_membre=g.id_membre
  LEFT JOIN `factures` f ON s.id_membre=f.addedfrom
                         AND f.status=2
 GROUP BY s.id_membre
```

Comment: thank you but when i try it i didnt get the correct number of the staff, i have 8 members i get 5 records, and in the field of Membre i get `'NULL'`

Answer (score 0):

You're only running left joins, so without knowing all the tables my first instinct is that the members themselves are missing from the 'groups' table, the first table selected. Alternatively, try removing the WHERE and AND criteria and seeing if the missing users come back.

Comment: thank you, i removed the `WHERE` and even with that i didnt get all the members